# Do multiple pages with the same title and meta description but different content penalise the overall site?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, meta-tags, penalty

I have been experiencing a ranking drop for my site in the last few  days.

I found there about six pages that have been indexed with the same eta tags but showing different content. Is this really bad in terms of SEO?

Comment: If they have different content, how valuable is that content? Have you copied from somewhere else? Is it keyword spam? Did your site have good ranking for a long time (i.e. at least a year) before it started to drop? Are you sure your pages are dropping and you've just not been searching your competition so much that Google is skewing your search results?

Comment: No I haven't copied contents from other sites. Yes, some pages seem to have duplicate content but not all.

Comment: I'm not completly sure about the key reason of my rank drop is duplucate meta. A year ago i had shifted my site from country specific domain to. com.  And also had changed my hosting including the server location. My keywords are ranking last at serp may be beacause of one of those reason.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "meta title".   The page title is not a meta tag.  I edited your question to clarify this based on your further comments.

Answer (score 2):

I will allow myself to give an answer from the point of view of Google because I know a little with their documentation.

Duplicate content (regardless of location - in the metadata or in the main content of the web page) has the following negative result. The presence of duplicate content of the website does not allow Google to determine the relevant content for a search query. In this case, Google may simply ignore the duplicate content of your website and use the content of another website that may not have duplicate content.

To eliminate this problem, Google recommends using **[canonical meta-links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066)** for the main content.

To create relevant meta titles, **[Google recommends the following](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624)**:

> Avoid repeated or boilerplate titles. It’s important to have distinct,
>   descriptive titles for each page on your site.

Google gives the similar recommendation for creating relevant meta descriptions:

> Differentiate the descriptions for different pages. Identical or
>   similar descriptions on every page of a site aren't helpful when
>   individual pages appear in the web results. In these cases, we're less
>   likely to display the boilerplate text. Wherever possible, create
>   descriptions that accurately describe the specific page. Use
>   site-level descriptions on the main home page or other aggregation
>   pages, and use page-level descriptions everywhere else.

Therefore, duplicate content can have a negative impact on your web pages in search results.